# Select a DataRow from a DataRow [] collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code :

```
DataRow[] row = ByTotalTemplate.Select("TEMPLATE_ID=" + DisTemplateID);
```

A row contains `TEMPLATE_ID`,`MIN_AMOUNT`,`MAX_AMOUNT` and `DISCOUNT`

Now I want to select a row where a given amount is between `MIN_AMOUNT` and `MAX_AMOUNT`

I tried to do this :

```
DataRow amountRow = row.Select("MIN_AMOUNT<" + quantity + " AND MAX_AMOUNT>" + quantity);
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: did you get an error or you were not able to get the desired row?

Comment: Is your variable also misspelled as qunatity instead of quantity? Maybe there is the problem! :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with the expression  syntax i would use Linq:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = ByTotalTemplate.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.Field<int>("TEMPLATE_ID") == DisTemplateID
                    && r.Field<int>("MIN_AMOUNT") < quantity
                    && r.Field<int>("MAX_AMOUNT") > quantity);
```

If you want a new DataTable with the filtered result:

```
DataTable table = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that `CopyToDataTable` throws an exception if there are no rows since it must derive the columns from the rows. So you have to check it before. You could use:

```
DataTable table = ByTotalTemplate.Clone();
if(rows.Any())
    table = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want an array instead:

```
DataRow[] rowArray = rows.ToArray();
```

If you just want the first row:

```
DataRow row = rows.FirstOrDefault(); // can be null if there is no matching row
```

Btw, your problem was that you used `DataTable.Select` on a `DataRow[]`

Comment: If 'rows' does not contain any entries, CopyToDataTable() will give an exception, check rows.any() before using the method to be sure it has something to copy.

Comment: @Enrico: i have edited my answer to show how you could avoid the exception.

Comment: dataTable.AsEnumerable() was the one I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to select rows again from your `DataTable` if you want to use `Select()` method

```
DataRow[] rowsBetween = ByTotalTemplate.Select("TEMPLATE_ID = " + DisTemplateID + " AND MIN_AMOUNT < " + qunatity + " AND MAX_AMOUNT > " + qunatity);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        DataRow[] row = ByTotalTemplate.Select("TEMPLATE_ID=" + DisTemplateID);
        //
        //some use of **row** here 
        //than after select record from **row**
        DataRow[] amountRow = row.CopyToDataTable().Select("MIN_AMOUNT < " + qunatity + " AND MAX_AMOUNT > " + qunatity);
```